# What programming languages are used by different GIS platforms?

Tags: internationalization

Suppose a programmer has no knowledge of GIS, but wants to leverage his/her programming skills to get into GIS.  Please list different GIS platforms, packages, etc. that use a particular language.

(I was thinking, [as suggested](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3160/59), about doing a simple test of the code formatting capability of StackExchange.  I figure this might be done in the context of a useful answer.)

When you answer, if the language is one of those listed below, please post a code snippet and test the formatting to make sure it works.  Here's an [excerpt from Jeff Atwood's answer on meta-stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/149222).

The spec is:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

You may use either a **tag** or a **prettify language code** to specify, though prettify language codes are always guaranteed to work regardless of what language the tag happens to be set to.

Use `<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag -->` to use the given highlighting for all the following code blocks.

The complete list of supported prettify code languages is:

- lang-none
- lang-default
- lang-bsh
- lang-c
- lang-cpp
- lang-cs
- lang-csh
- lang-css
- lang-hs
- lang-html
- lang-java
- lang-js
- lang-lisp
- lang-lua
- lang-ml
- lang-perl
- lang-php
- lang-py
- lang-proto
- lang-rb
- lang-scala
- lang-sh
- lang-sql
- lang-vb
- lang-xml

Answer (score 11):

Some geospatial scripting languages:

**1) Python/Jython**

**Python/Jython alone:**

Python and Jython can be used alone for processing geospatial data without any software, using modules like osgeo (GDAL / OGR), PySAL, Shapely, Fiona, Pyshp,..., see [Python Package Index, Topic:GIS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&show=all&c=391) or [Geoscript](http://geoscript.org/) (Jython). There are many examples on GST

**as scripting language in applications**

QGIS, GRASS GIS, GvSIG, OpenJump or Geoserver (and ArcGIS, see above) use Python/Jython for scripting:

- Quantum GIS ( **Python**, 1.8, changes in master version)

```py
from qgis.core import *
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
        geom= elem.geometry()
        attrs = elem.attributeMap()
```

- GRASS GIS (**Python**)

```py
from grass.script import raster as grassr
grassr.raster_info('s_newfrst3@moi')
{'north':118869.900569, 'timestamp': '"none"', 'min': -456.08587646484398,
'datatype': 'FCELL', 'max': 265.500732421875, 'ewres':
 14.008076920000001, 'vertical_datum': '', 'west': 164160.653425,
 'units': '', 'title': ' (s_newfrst3)', 'east': 176641.849961, 'nsres':
  13.976472729999999, 'south': 112552.534895}
```

- GvSIG (**Jython**)

```py
from gvsig import *
layer = currentLayer()
features = layer.features()
for feature in features:
  geom = feature.geometry()
  values = feature.getValues()
```

- OpenJump (**Jython**)

```py
from org.openjump.util.python.JUMP_GIS_Framework import *
layer = getSelectedLayers()
for i in layer.iterator():
    print layer.name  
# first element of the layer
fc = layer[0].featureCollectionWrapper
for elem in range(fc.size):
    obj = fc.features[elem] 
    geom = obj.getGeometry()
```

- GeoServer (**Jython**)

```py
from geoserver import Catalog
cat = Catalog('aff_geol')
print cat.stores()
[u'affleurements', u'cartes']
st = cat['affleurements']
print st.layers()
[u'affs']
l = st['affs']
print l.count()
3214
print l.bounds()
(107206.74,148102.45,114110.46,157514.40, EPSG:31370)
```

and you can also use other Java libraries like the [Java Topology Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite)( **Jython**):

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.../jts-1.8.0/lib/jts-1.8.jar')   
from com.vividsolutions.jts.geom import Point
```

**2) Bash**

GRASS GIS uses Bash (shell and scripts (.sh))

```sh
GRASS 6.4.2 (geol):~ > v.out.ascii in=ligneprofil format=standard | grep '^ '|\r.profile -c in=MNT res=30 output=profil.pts
```

**3) R** (no prettify code language)

You can use R for all geospatial treatments, see [CRAN Task View: Analysis of Spatial Data](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html):

```sh
library(maptools)
geol <-readShapePoly("cal.shp")
library(rgdal)
geol = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="cal")
library(PBSmapping)
geol = importShapefile("cal.shp")
library(shapefiles)
geol <- read.shapefile("cal")
# PostGIS
geol = readOGR("PG:dbname=test", "cal")
```

but GRASS GIS can also uses R directly:

```sh
GRASS 6.4.2 (geol):~ > R
R version ....
> library(spgrass6) 
> G <- gmeta6() # paramètres de Grass, région etc.
> montrait <- readRAST6(c("geologie", "mnt"),cat=c(TRUE, FALSE),  ignore.stderr=TRUE,plugin=NULL)
```

**4) [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/)(Java)**

OpenJump can also use Beanshell (console or script)

```java
layer = wc.layerManager .getLayer("road").featureCollectionWrapper;
getLongest() {
    max = -1;
    for (f : layer.features) { length = f.geometry.length; if (f.geometry.length > max) {max = length; result = f;}
}
return result;
print(getLongest().ID);
```

**5) [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) (Java), [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and JavaScript**

You can use theses languages with GeoScript, see [examples](http://geoscript.org/index.html)

**6)  [JEQL Query Language](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jeql/main.html)**

As shown by Martin Davis ([label jeql](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.be/search/label/jeql))

```java
shapefileReader t file: "agder/agder_buffer.shp";
t = select geomUnionMem(GEOMETRY) g from t;
ShapefileWriter t file: "result.shp";
```

Answer (score 6):

Old school GIS without computers. lang-none

```
    Overlay acetate on paper maps, buffer with rulers,
    symbolize with dry-erase markers.
    No computers, so no language needed.
```

Answer (score 3):

C# can be used to program ArcGIS.  With ArcObjects this involves dealing with a lot of COM interop, so any knowledge there would be very helpful.

C# can also be used (without dealing with much interop) in the ArcGIS for WPF and the ArcGIS for Silverlight SDK's.

```cs
public static IPolyline MakePolyline(IPoint p1, IPoint p2)
{
    var polyline = new PolylineClass() as IPolyline;
    ((IZAware)polyline).ZAware = true;
    ((IMAware)polyline).MAware = true;
    polyline.SpatialReference = p1.SpatialReference;
    ((IPointCollection)polyline).AddPoint(p1);
    ((IPointCollection)polyline).AddPoint(p2);
    return polyline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS since 10.0 uses Python via the `arcpy` module.

Using the Python that comes with ArcGIS:

```py
import arcpy

# Make dictionary of lookup table
dictCityProvince = {}
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(r"C:\temp\test.gdb\CityProvinceLookup")
for row in rows:
    dictCityProvince[row.CITY] = row.PROVINCE
del row,rows
```

If this works, then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of WebGIS development is done via JavaScript. Here is some sample code using OpenLayers:

```js
        var lon = 5;
        var lat = 40;
        var zoom = 5;
        var map, layer;

        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);

            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Development for the Android Platform is done using Java.

Here is some code from the OsmDroid project:

```java
/**
 * Logs all Location-changes to <code>mRouteRecorder</code>.
 *
 * @author plusminus
 */
private class SampleLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            if (SampleMapActivity.this.mDoGPSRecordingAndContributing)
                SampleMapActivity.this.mRouteRecorder.add(loc,
                        SampleMapActivity.this.mNumSatellites);

            SampleMapActivity.this.onLocationChanged(loc);
        } else {
            SampleMapActivity.this.onLocationLost();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of projects are developed in C++.

Here is some source code from QGis:

```cpp
/**
  Open the specified project file; prompt to save previous project if necessary.
  Used to process a commandline argument or OpenDocument AppleEvent.
  */
void QgisApp::openProject( const QString & fileName )
{
  // possibly save any pending work before opening a different project
  if ( saveDirty() )
  {
    // error handling and reporting is in addProject() function
    addProject( fileName );
  }
  return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C can be used with the [ArcSDE C API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/capi.htm).

I see that it can be downloaded for 10.1 [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/66/metaid/1914), but is not mentioned in the [list of API's on the help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/).  I don't see any online help for 10.1, only [10.0 help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/welcome.htm).

```or-tag-here
void check_rc_(SE_CONNECTION Connection, SE_STREAM Stream, LONG rc, 
                 char *comment, LONG line_no, char* file_name) ;
static LONG S_create_layer (SE_CONNECTION connection, CHAR *table,CHAR *keyword,LONG precision);
static LONG S_point_cases(SE_CONNECTION connection,const CHAR* table);
static LONG S_line_cases(SE_CONNECTION connection,const CHAR* table);
static LONG S_polygon_cases(SE_CONNECTION connection,const CHAR* table);

LONG  main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    CHAR            *server, 
                    *user, 
                    *passwd, 
                    *database,
                    *instance,
                    *rslt_layer_name;
    SE_CONNECTION   conn;
    SE_ERROR        error;
    LONG            result;
    BOOL            all_step_passed=TRUE;

    if(argc<7){
        printf("usage: %s <server> <instance> <database> <user> <passwd> <result_layer>",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    server=argv[1];
    instance=argv[2];
    database=argv[3];
    user=argv[4];
    passwd=argv[5];
    rslt_layer_name=argv[6];

    printf("\nConnecting to SDE server %s:%s as %s\n",server,instance,user);
    result = SE_connection_create( server, instance, database, user, passwd, &error, &conn );
    check_rc_return_on_failure(conn,NULL,result,"SE_connection_create");
    printf("\t---Connected");

    /*Create a layer to store results*/
    printf("\n\nCreating a layer to store results......\n");
    result=S_create_layer (conn,rslt_layer_name,"DEFAULTS",64);
    if(result!=SE_SUCCESS)
        return result;
    else
        printf("\tLayer %s created.\n",rslt_layer_name);

    /*point shapes*/
    printf("\n\n***************************************************************************\n");
    printf("* Generating buffer for point shapes......                                *\n");
    printf("***************************************************************************\n");
    result=S_point_cases(conn,rslt_layer_name);
    if(result!=SE_SUCCESS)
        return result;

    /* line shapes */
    printf("\n\n***************************************************************************\n");
    printf("* Generating buffer for line shapes......                                 *\n");
    printf("***************************************************************************\n");
    result=S_line_cases(conn,rslt_layer_name);
    if(result!=SE_SUCCESS)
        return result;

    /* polygon shapes */
    printf("\n\n***************************************************************************\n");
    printf("* Generating buffer for polygon shapes......                              *\n");
    printf("***************************************************************************\n");
    result=S_polygon_cases(conn,rslt_layer_name);
    if(result!=SE_SUCCESS)
        return result;

    SE_connection_free(conn);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic

```vb
Sub SelectByBufferedLine()
    Dim xy As String
    xy = InputBox("Enter x,y coordinates for line in metres. x1,y1 x2,y2 ...xn,yn e.g. 200000,200000 250000,200000 280000,250000", "Select by buffered line (keyboard input)")
    If (xy = "") Then Exit Sub
    xy = Replace(xy, " ", ",")
    xy = Replace(xy, ",,", ",")
    Dim arr As Object
    arr = Split(xy, ",")
    Dim numvals As Integer, n As Object
    numvals = (UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1)) + 1
    If (numvals < 4) Or ((numvals Mod 2) <> 0) Then Exit Sub
    For Each n In arr
        If (Not IsNumeric(n)) Then Exit Sub
    Next
    '
    ' Create polyline from array of x,y's
    '
    Dim pt As IPoint
    pt = New Geometry.Point
    Dim pGeometry As IGeometry
    pGeometry = New Polyline
    Dim thePointCollection As IPointCollection
    thePointCollection = pGeometry
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) - 1 Step 2
        pt.PutCoords(arr(i), arr(i + 1))
        thePointCollection.AddPoint(pt)
    Next
    '
    ' Buffer the line
    '
    Dim topoOP As ITopologicalOperator
    Dim theBufferPoly As IPolygon
    topoOP = pGeometry
    topoOP.Simplify()
    Dim bufdist As String
    bufdist = InputBox("Enter buffer distance(m)", "Select by buffered line", 0)
    If (Not IsNumeric(bufdist)) Then Exit Sub
    theBufferPoly = topoOP.Buffer(bufdist)
    pGeometry = theBufferPoly
    '
    ' Query the Active Layer
    '
    Call SpatialQuery(My.ArcMap.Application, pGeometry)
    '
    ' Set Visible Extent
    '
    Dim pDoc As IMxDocument = My.ArcMap.Document
    Dim theExtent As IEnvelope
    theExtent = pGeometry.Envelope
    theExtent.Expand(2, 2, True)
    pDoc.ActiveView.Extent = theExtent
    pDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()
End Sub
```