# Career advice in Gis field

Tags: qgis, career

I am a B.Tech graduate(2013) in Geo Informatics and Geo Technology.Presently, i am working i an company as Junoir Executive in Gis . I also know some  programming languages like "V.B.net" and C#.My doubt is how can i improve my Career strength in this field so that i can earn handful salary ?

Comment: I think this question is too broad and does not fit here. Looks like LinkedIn question. Please have a look similiar questions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/883/how-do-i-develop-my-gis-programming-skills ,http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/what-programming-languages-are-used-by-different-gis-platforms

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a book on Amazon called [Careers in GIS: an Unfiltered Guide to Finding a GIS Job](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0080KYSTQ) which you might find useful when searching for a job and deciding which track to follow.

Another thing I find really useful is the [Geospatial Technology Competency Model](http://www.careeronestop.org/competencymodel/pyramid_download.aspx?GEO=Y) which gives you a good idea on how to build your career in geospatial industry.

Comment: nice explanation and the useful links.. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: No problem, Sunil! :)